# Magento 2 : Sales Order Report Adding Text Field

Tags: magento2, admin, sales-order, reports

How do I add custom text field under `sales -> orders -> filters`? If you look under filters there is a field called "Ship to name" you can type query here. But instead, I wanted a field called "products" so I can filter products names.

Thanks in advance